# No longer able to go online with 13.10

Tags: 13.10, login, internet, password

Bought my Computer from ebay, loaded with Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10. Came with a disk with Ubuntu 13.10.

I loaded Ubuntu 13.10 and called who I purchased computer from. He walked me through setting up Ubuntu 13.10. It worked great until one day I miss typed my password or something else happened, and now I am able to log on with my password, but not able to get online.

Also I see at the top of the screen, in the dark line, my password listed until i log in.  Is that normal ?

I am a noob to Ubuntu, all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Michael: Thank you for the fast response.  I tried ALT + CTL+ F6:  I get a request for "password".  I have tried everyone I know.  No Joy.

Comment: ALT + CTL +F6 will sometimes give me a "tty6" then ask for "password" in new line.

Comment: It would be helpful if you put some effort into your grammar. I have no idea what you want to communicate.

Comment: Solved my problem by changing the loading from my hard drive to my disk drive..  Reloaded 13.10 It takes forever to load this way, however, I can go online now.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Did you use the Live-Mode ("Try Ubuntu") ? You can also backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu. There is a newer version 14.04 you can download.

Answer (score 0):

Try this key-shortcut; <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> and type the following command in `tty`, followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
hash -lt / -d
```

Might work fine.